# ¿Como ejecutar una funcion del MainActivity fuera de él?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

el problema es que al ejecutar una función fuera de la clase principal(en mi caso un servicio) me da error si ejecuto acciones que requieran View.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit tv:TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

 tv = findViewById(R.id.text)

}


    fun inicio(){

        tv.setText("Mi texto")

    }
```

En na clase que quiero realizar la acción:

```
 class Myclase{

 fun myclase() {

MainActivity().inicio()

 }
}
```

Sin embargo si le paso el Context me lo ejecuta sin problemas os pongo un ejemplo con un Toast:

En na clase que quiero realizar la acción:

```
 class Myclase{

 fun myclase() {

MainActivity().inicio(this)

 }
}
```

Y en el MainActivity:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit tv:TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

tv = findViewById(R.id.text)

}


fun inicio(ctx:Context){


    Toast.makeText(ctx,"text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
```

En este caso me ejecuta la función sin problemas. Ahora si la solución correcta es esta, ¿Como ejecuto el TextView con el contexto que le he pasado?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco lo que intentas hacer? Me parece que el problema es más de lógica que de otra cosa, debido a que estás organizando mal las cosas o intentando que funcionen al revés. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué tienes que usar elementos de la vista fuera de una Activity? ¿Acaso no debería ser justo lo contrario?

Comment: Yo creo que la activity tiene el focus y un servicio está corriendo en segundo plano.  Al finalizar el servicio igual quiere refrescar el valor del TextView... a ver si puede aclarlo.

Answer (score -1):

#### ¿Cómo llamar a un método de MainActivity desde otra clase?

**KOTLIN:**

Puedes usar el objeto companion que es en realidad un Singleton, dentro define una variable como `MainActivity`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

       private val TAG = "MainActivity"

        companion object {
            val instance = MainActivity()
        }

       fun myMethod() {
           //do something...
       }
}
```

De esta forma puedes llamar desde otra clase el método de `MainActivity`, accediendo mediante su instancia

```
 val mainActivity = MainActivity.instance
 mainActivity.myMethod()
```

**JAVA:**

En tu `MainActivity` declara una variable de tipo `MainActivity` e iniciala dentro del constructor,  crea un método `getInstance()` donde retornarás esta variable.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static MainActivity instance;

    public MainActivity() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
       //do something...
    }
)
```

De esta forma puedes llamar desde otra clase el método de `MainActivity`, accediendo mediante su instancia:

```
public Class AnotherClass() {
     //llama a método de MainActivity
     MainActivity.getInstance().myMethod();
}
```

---

- Obviamente debido a que se hace referencia a `MainActivity`, debes de consciente que dependiendo de la estructura de tu aplicación puede ser que `MainActivity` no exista, por lo que tienes que validar si `MainActivity` es diferente de NULL.

Comment: **Esto puede tener graves consecuencias**. Hay cosas que se llaman con el ciclo de vida de las Actividades, por ejemplo, acceder a los recursos `getResources()`, una transaccion entre Fragment, mostrar un Toast y si el Contexto no esta vivo, le lanzara repetidas veces excepciones. Implementar Singleton en una instancia de una clase que esta atada a un ciclo de vida no es lo ideal. Lo que puedes hacer es intentar crear una Clase singleton que defina una interfaz y dicha interfaz se suscriba/desuscriba en los ciclos de vida correspondientes a la Actividad.

Comment: ahhh ok, agrega tu respuesta.